# Any iPad visualization/layout tool out there?

Tags: iphone, ipad, user-interface, layout

Its just plain cumbersome to try out CGRect values for subview frames etc on paper and then on code and on the simulator. Get the wrong and you have to try it all over again. And so on.

Is there any tool out there for the iPad which simulates the screen XY system and on which we might try out placing views on coordinates and see how the layout looks like?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with Interface Builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely invest some time on Interface Builder. Since you are developing for fixed sceen-size devices, you actually dont need advanced layout managers like the ones in Android or Qt. What you need most of the time is good alignment and spacing, and Interface Builder is perfect for that. I know, it feels like hard-coding everything, and it bothers you if you are a clean-code junkie, but that's the efficient way to go for iOS devices. For unknown number of items, or unknown length text which shouldn't be clipped, just use UITableVeiw's so it scrolls and shows the whole content properly.

The vendor (Apple) exploits fixed screen-size situation to the bone (that's why iPhone4 has exactly twice the resolution on both axis), so why wouldn't you?